# Textmate file display

Tags: textmate

[image]

I don't like how Textmate will add an ellipsis to fit the a long file name in the Project Panel. Can and how do I get it to display the file name in full and just use something like a horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

For better or worse, it appears to be an Apple design thing, and was [discussed on the TextMate mailing list](http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2007-September/022401.html). However, you can make the drawer wider to fit the name in.

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew that. It's an okay way for me to display the files in the Project Pane, but I don't want that to be so wide all the time. If I had a scrollbar, I could just scroll over quickly then back again.